# Preventing Duplicate Records in Registration Process with in java and MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm currently facing an issue with a Java registration process that involves checking for existing records, performing some processing, and then adding records to a MongoDB database. Unfortunately, this multi-step process is leading to the creation of duplicate records.

Background:
The registration process I'm dealing with follows these steps:

1. Check if the record already exists in the database.
2. Perform additional processing on the registration data.
3. Add the processed data to a MongoDB database collection.

Challenges:

**Synchronization**: I've considered using synchronization to prevent duplicates, but there are already two synchronized methods within the same process. Adding more synchronization could lead to performance issues.

**Indexing**: While indexing could help prevent duplicates, our uniqueness criteria are complex and can't be fully addressed using a single indexed field. There are multiple cases for uniqueness.

What are some alternative strategies to effectively prevent duplicate records in a complex registration process without relying solely on synchronization or indexing?

Comment: Realistically, just don't. This is what unique indexes are for. Trying to work around them will only bite you in the end.

Comment: And if that's not enough to convince you (it never is...), think about all the ways this check can miss: Two requests can both do the check, then both do the insert. Or one does a check, the insert but not the processing, while the other does the check, finds it's OK, does the insert but then the processing makes it a duplicate. Or the other way around. Or perhaps the processing can make a duplicate, not a duplicate. Et cetera.

Comment: "_our uniqueness criteria are complex and can't be fully addressed using a single indexed field_" - unique indexes can be compound as opposed to being limited to single field. See also [Unique Compound Index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-compound-index) in the official documentation.

Comment: Unique compound index also can't be use in our case , is there any other solution for handling multiple request at same time??